# PowerShell and Jar Execution

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to execute a jar file from PowerShell from a remote PowerShell session. Below is my current script block and it does not seem to work on remote machine. It appears that the jar file is picking up an anonymous credential but if I put a username command before the jar I get the actual user.

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "servera" -ScriptBlock {
    java -cp "multiplejars" main "arguments"
} -Credential $global:credential
```

This is my current error.

> caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. ClientConnectionId:7071e2b2-bad9-48db-b01a-d86665c783ff

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue. The error is from you Java code, so you'd need to show that code (or at least usage instructions for the Java program) and the actual `java` commandline for us to be able to debug this.

Comment: I am basically trying to use integrated security with this jar. 
java -jar liquibase.jar \
      --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
      --classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \
      --changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
      --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle" \
      --username=scott \
      --password=tiger \
      update

Comment: Now please post your *actual* commandline rather copy/pasting an example from the Liquibase documentation. You may obfuscate credentials and hostnames, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. It seems it was the CredSSP was disabled on the local machine. Scripts and jar were fine. It was just that setting missing.